# ElementTree parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse below xml using Python and `ElementTree` however I'm running into some errors.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
tree = file.xml

for house in tree.findall('.//HOUSE'):
        HOUSE_ID = house.find('ID').text
        ASSET_ID = house.find('ASSET_ID').text
        IP = house.find('IP').text
        FOLLOW_UP= house.find('FOLLOW_UP').text
        NODE_ID= house.find('NODE_ID').text
        ADDRESS = house.find('ADDRESS')
        if ADDRESS is None:
            ADDRESS = ''
        else:
            ADDRESS = ADDRESS.text
        LAST_VISIT_DATETIME = host.find('LAST_VISIT_DATETIME').text
        DOMOTIC = house.find('DOMOTIC')
        if DOMOTIC is None:
            DOMOTIC = ''
        else:
            DOMOTIC = DOMOTIC.text
        ITEM_ID = house.find('ITEM_ID')
        if ITEM_ID is None:
            ITEM_ID = ''
        else:
            ITEM_ID = ITEM_ID.text


        print(HOUSE_ID + "," + ASSET_ID + "," + IP + "," + FOLLOW_UP + "," + NODE_ID + "," + ADDRESS + "," + LAST_VISIT_DATETIME + "," + ADDRESS + "," + LAST_VISIT_DATETIME)
```

This is the XML:

```
<OUTPUT>
    <RESPONSE>
        <DATETIME>2020-10-26T11:38:35Z</DATETIME>
        <HOUSE_LIST>
            <HOUSE>
                <ID>10808749</ID>
                <ASSET_ID>1234</ASSET_ID>
                <IP>192.168.0.1</IP>
                <TRACKING_METHOD>IP</TRACKING_METHOD>
                <NODE_ID>0</NODE_ID>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <![CDATA[XXX]]>
                </ADDRESS>
                <LAST_VISIT_DATETIME>2020-08-28T09:16:26Z</LAST_VISIT_DATETIME>
                <LAST_COMM_DATE>2020-08-28T08:48:38Z</LAST_COMM_DATE>
                <LAST_COMM_DURATION>982</LAST_COMM_DURATION>
                <ITEM_LIST>
                    <ITEM>
                        <ITEM_ID>13607</ITEM_ID>
                        <TYPE>Potential</TYPE>
                        <USAGE>3</USAGE>
                        <LOCATION>443</LOCATION>
                        <ABCD>aa</ABCD>>
                        <ABD>1</ABD>
                        <DESCRIPTION>
                            <![CDATA[AAAAAA]]>
                        </DESCRIPTION>
                        <STATUS>New</STATUS>
                        <FIRST_FOUND_DATETIME>2020-08-28T08:48:38Z</FIRST_FOUND_DATETIME>
                        <LAST_FOUND_DATETIME>2020-08-28T08:48:38Z</LAST_FOUND_DATETIME>
                        <TIMES_FOUND>1</TIMES_FOUND>
                        <LAST_TEST_DATETIME>2020-08-28T08:48:38Z</LAST_TEST_DATETIME>
                        <LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME>2020-08-28T09:16:26Z</LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME>
                        <IS_IGNORED>0</IS_IGNORED>
                        <IS_DISABLED>0</IS_DISABLED>
                        <LAST_PROCESSED_DATETIME>2020-08-28T09:16:26Z</LAST_PROCESSED_DATETIME>
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM>
```

I'd like to print the list of items in each house, however it only prints one of them.

Comment: First, your xml is invalid; please edit the question and fix it. Second, what exactly is your expected output? Third, can  you use lxml instead of ElementTree?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `ITEM` element are repeated inside `HOUSE/ITEM_LIST` and to print list of items in each house it would be needed to iterate over `ITEM` elements in the same way as you iterate over `HOUSE` elements:

```
for item in house.findall('./ITEM_LIST/ITEM'):
    ITEM_ID = item.find('ITEM_ID')
    if ITEM_ID is None:
        ITEM_ID = ''
    else:
        ITEM_ID = ITEM_ID.text
    print(ITEM_ID)
```